# ZendFramework 1.12 and PHPUnit Error: include_once(PageRegex.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I'm trying to run some unit tests with PHPunit on my ZF install.

I've followed this tutorial to get it setup:

and I'm getting this error:

`1) FirsttestTest::testCanDoUnitTest 
include_once(PageRegex.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Had a google, but cannot find anything

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem, I simply didn't have the right include path setup.